# Setting line number color works in command mode but not in .vimrc

Tags: vim, colors, highlight

I want to set the color of line numbers in vim and I can do it like so:

```
:highlight LineNr  ctermfg=220
```

but when I try to set it from `.vimrc` it doesn't work:

```
hi LineNr ctermfg=220
```

**EDIT**

I am using solarized theme with `vundle` as follows:

```
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/vundle/                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
call vundle#begin()

" let Vundle manage Vundle
" required!
Plugin 'gmarik/vundle'

Plugin 'altercation/vim-colors-solarized'

" Solarized theme                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
let g:solarized_termtrans=1
set background=dark
let g:solarized_termcolors=256
colorscheme solarized
```

Comment: have you tried putting that line at the end of your vimrc?

Comment: @Kent That's what I have done. Nothing changed when I load a new file in new instance of vim after this change in `.vimrc`

Comment: the problem cannot be reproduced here. start your vim with your hi setting, run this cmd: `:verbose hi LineNr` you will see who and when touched your `hi LineNr`

Comment: @Kent Ahh..ok.. it was because of solarized theme that I use : `::verbose hi LineNr
LineNr         xxx ctermfg=239 ctermbg=235 guifg=Yellow
        Last set from ~/.vim/bundle/vim-colors-solarized/colors/solarized.vim`

Comment: but if you did add your `hi` line **at the end of** your vimrc, it should work after that colors theme, shouldn't it? have put that at the bottom of your vimrc?

Comment: @Kent I did put it at the very last line and still it does not work. When I find the appropriate place in `solarized` theme's code to change this setting it works.

Comment: well then I cannot help more without seeing the vimrc.

Comment: @Kent I have added `.vimrc`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure why (and, whatever my feelings toward solarized are, I would really love to know) but this form seems to work:

```
execute "hi LineNr ctermfg=220"
```